# Spring MongoTemplate bulk upserts are not performed onto the collection

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I've got a MongoDB collection with the following document structure:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Document
public class CustomerRouteManagementReportDocument implements TransactionDocument {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String customerId;
    // ... other properties
    private List<RouteHistoryEvent> routeHistoryEvents;
    // ... other properties
}
```

Essentially, the following method should perform a **bulk upsert**: if a matching entry is found, it should append the first item from the `routeHistoryEvents` item into the existing document' `routeHistoryEvents` array. Otherwise, a whole new `CustomerRouteManagementReportDocument` should be inserted into the collection.

```java
@Service
@Slf4j
public class CustomerRouteManagementReportRepositoryAdapter extends AbstractRepositoryAdapter<CustomerRouteManagementReport, CustomerRouteManagementReportDocument, CustomerRouteManagementReportDataRepository> implements CustomerRouteManagementReportRepository {

    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    @Autowired
    public CustomerRouteManagementReportRepositoryAdapter(ModelMapper mapper, CustomerRouteManagementReportDataRepository repository, MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        super(mapper, repository, CustomerRouteManagementReport.class, CustomerRouteManagementReportDocument.class);
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }
    //... other methods

    @Override
    public Integer upsertTall(List<CustomerRouteManagementReportDocument> customerRouteManagementReports) {
        BulkOperations bulkOps = mongoTemplate.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.ORDERED, CustomerRouteManagementReportDocument.class);

        try {
            List<Pair<Query, Update>> updates = new ArrayList<>();

            customerRouteManagementReports.stream().forEach(customerRouteManagementReport -> {
                Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("customerId").is(customerRouteManagementReport.getCustomerId()));
                Update update = new Update();

                update.addToSet("routeHistoryEvents").value(customerRouteManagementReport.getRouteHistoryEvents().get(0));
                updates.add(Pair.of(query, update));

            });

            bulkOps.upsert(updates);
            BulkWriteResult result = bulkOps.execute();
            log.info("== BULK RESULT: {}, INSERTED: {}", result, result.getInsertedCount());
            return result.getInsertedCount();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("ERROR {}: IN UPSERTION  {}", e.getClass().toGenericString(), e.getMessage());
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that **no updates nor insertions are being made and no exception is raised either**. I've tried with both an empty collection and a collection loaded with documents that will meet the `query` condition and should be updated, but my log simply reads:
`== BULK RESULT: AcknowledgedBulkWriteResult{insertedCount=0, matchedCount=4, removedCount=0, modifiedCount=4, upserts=[]}, INSERTED: 0`

However, in debugging, the method *is* called and it shows the appropriate number of `Pair`s for the number of objects that the usecase receives to process:
[image]

No `MongoTemplate` logs are issued (not even for the `find` operation that, I presume, it must perform in order to update my collection) which leads me to think that maybe my class doesn't have a proper `MongoTemplate` configured. However, there are no connection errors thrown either. This is our config class for MongoDB:

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "spring.data.mongodb.uri-report")
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(basePackages = "package name",
        reactiveMongoTemplateRef = ReportMongoConfig.REPORT_REACTIVE_MONGO_TEMPLATE)
public class ReportMongoConfig {

    protected static final String REPORT_REACTIVE_MONGO_TEMPLATE = "reportReactiveMongoTemplate";

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri-report}")
    private String connectionStringReport;

    @Bean
    public ConnectionString getConnectionDataBaseReport() {
        return new ConnectionString(connectionStringReport);
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveMongoTemplate reportReactiveMongoTemplate(MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter) {
        return new ReactiveMongoTemplate(reactiveReportMongoDatabaseFactory(getConnectionDataBaseReport()), mappingMongoConverter);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter) {
        return new MongoTemplate(reportMongoDBFactory(getConnectionDataBaseReport()), mappingMongoConverter);
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory reactiveReportMongoDatabaseFactory(ConnectionString getConnectionDataBaseExperience) {
        return new SimpleReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory(getConnectionDataBaseExperience);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory reportMongoDBFactory(ConnectionString connectionString) {
        return new SimpleMongoClientDbFactory(connectionString);
    }

}
```

I'm wondering if there's an injection issue when providing the appropriate `MongoTemplate` bean to the repository class or if there's an issue with the queries built inside the `upsertAll` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that somewhere else in a the application there's another `MongoTemplate` bean connected to a different collection. Organizing the beans using `@Primary` and `@Qualifier` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that no updates nor insertions are being made and no
> exception is raised either.

Log

> BULK RESULT: AcknowledgedBulkWriteResult{insertedCount=0,
> matchedCount=4, removedCount=0, modifiedCount=4, upserts=[]},
> INSERTED: 0

The above statement is wrong. As is clearly shown from the logs there are 4 updates -> `matchedCount=4 modifiedCount=4`.

So you need to check why somehow there is a match that triggers an update instead of an insert during this upsert.

Comment: That's a manual log that I wrote: it simply prints the object returned by `bulkOps.execute()`

Comment: @LeperAffinity666 this returned object contains the information after the query execution https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/BulkWriteResult.html. So there are 4 updates

Comment: Thank you. It's weird, because the test that threw that log was made when the collection was empty.

Comment: @LeperAffinity666 check if the application and you when you manually connect to inspect actually connect to the exact same mongo instance. Please don't forget to accept the answer if it has helped you solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm connected to the same instance both from the program and nosql booster